# Whereabouts of oldest extant source for Apollonius’ *Conics*, Books I - IV

Tags: reference-request, ancient-greece

Regarding *Conics*, it is widely written, e.g. [Rutger's site](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/Papers1999/schmarge.html),  that:

> The first four books have come down to us in the original Ancient Greek, but books V-VII are known only from an Arabic translation, while the eighth book has been lost entirely.

Try as i might, I am unable to locate any information on the origin and whereabouts of the oldest extant source for *Conics*; books 1-4 in original Greek.

The Bodleian Library, Oxford has an [Arabic translation of books 1 - 7](https://genius.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/exhibits/browse/conics/), giving a date of 1070.  This appears to be the manuscript used by Halley to produce his own edition.  It is not clear to me currently if this is accepted as the oldest extant Arabic translation. Some sites talk of a 9th century translation, but this dating has been challenged.

However, despite the many references to the older Greek copies of Books I - IV, I can find no information on their origin and whereabouts.

**Q**: What is the origin and whereabouts of the oldest, extant source for Apollonius’ *Conics*, Books I-IV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apollonius work have  been reedited recently at W. de Gruyter's (2008-9) 
: Apollonius de Perge, *Coniques*,
Texte grec et arabe etabli, traduit et commenté
Ed. by [Roshdi Rashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roshdi_Rashed), M. Decorps-Foulquier, M. Federspiel, (Livre I. Commentaire historique et mathématique, édition et traduction du texte arabe. 1.2: Livre I: Édition et traduction du texte grec Ed. by R. Roshdi, M. Decorps-Foulquier, M. Federspiel)

Roshdi in the preface (p.27) and also in a paper online about ["reediting apollonius"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39213165.pdf) states that the

> Eutocius’ edition of the first four books, as it has come down to us
>   in a manuscript from the 12th century, the Vaticanus. graec. 206

Comment: Thanks.  That looks right.  Sadly, the page of Greek sources listed at the [Vatican Library online](http://www.mss.vatlib.it/guii/scan/link1.jsp?fond=Vat.gr.) has a gap at catalogue number 206.